# WPF - navigating to a frame in multiple ways causes error

Tags: wpf, frame

I have a WPF window and a frame within the window that contains most of my content. In some cases, I will navigate directly to a URL with the frame and this will cause my frame.Currentsource to populate properly. However, in other cases, I will create a page object and then put the object directly in the frame.Navigate method but this will cause my frame.Currentsource to resolve to a NULL.

How can I make sure that my frame will always have a valid frame.Currentsource value?

Comment: I still be interested in hearing the community answer on this, but I did manage to create a workaround by checking for a null first and then rely on the Content type and the Name. This seems to be a lot more reliable that using CurrentSource